# Is it safe to perform a long action in a separate thread?

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, csv, azure

I'm dealing with a CSV file that's being imported Client side.
This CSV is supposed to contain some information which will be destinated to perform an update in one of the tables of my company's database.
My C# function process the file, looking for errors and, if no errors were found, it sends a bunch of update commands (files usually vary from 50 to 100000 lines).
Until now, I was performing the update in the same thread to execute the update (line by line), but it was getting a little slow, depending on the file, so I choose to send all the SQL to an Azure SQL Queue (which is a service that gets lots of "messages" and runs the SQL code agains the database), so that, the client wouldn't have to wait that much for the action to be performed.
It got a little faster, but still takes a long time (due to the requests to the Azure SQL Queue). So I noticed that putting that action in a separate thread worked and sent all the SQL to my Azure SQL Queue.

I got a little worried about it though. Is it really safe to perform long actions in separate threads? Is it reliable?

Comment: Define 'safe'.   You'll need to deal with handling/reporting errors since you can't just return a number or error string.

Comment: are you familiar with how to create temp tables on Sql Server then from there you can create an XML bulk Insert that can handle all the lines at once. I do this currently by converting the csv file into a datatable then once the data have been uploaded into the datatable and error checks etc are done.. then I have written my own function to convert the datatable to XML then one single call to a stored procedure I do bulk inserts to a single table via xml and temp tables

Comment: Using threads is almost never safe. Nature of the beast. But if it is a simple DB update, that is most likely not going to cause you any issues. If you can use asynchronous operations (and with DB providers, you probably can), I would go that route, as I think you would achieve your goal of user-responsiveness a little more safely.

Comment: @usr the 'is it reliable" is a concrete concern. For example in IIS starting a thread up to do background work is not reliable as IIS may shut down your AppDomain and call Thread.Abort on your thread.

Comment: The thread is not used to perform the updates, it just hits my Azure SQL Queue service. I got a WebJob which is responsible for getting the messages from the queue and running the SQL Code against the database.

Comment: It's hosted in Azure platform. My only doubt was if it could have a negative impact and whether it was granted that the method wouldn't reliably run, as I once had another multithreaded service (also hosted in Azure) and some of it's threads would just terminate for no reason.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that's why I ask: To find out whether this is IIS or what else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second thread is 100% like the main thread that you're used to working with. I wish I had some authority answer at hand but this is such a common practice that people don't write those anymore...

So, YES, off-loading the work to a second thread is safe and can be considered by most the recommended way to go by it.

**Edit 1**
Ok, if your thread is running on IIS, you need to register it or it will die because once the request/reponse cycle finishes it will kill it...

Comment: If he is developing a IIS application your statements don't hold up true. If you don't register the thread with IIS your AppDomain may be shut down before your thread completes its work.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes, but in this specific case, he stated in the first sentence that the action is happening in the client side... so i believe that, given the nature of the question, i don't think that this is the case... but fine, ill update my answer

Comment: To round off the update, to register the thread the easiest built in way to do it is use [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx) to start the thread up (and even then it still is not gaurnteed to finish, but you do get a CancellationToken you can watch to know when you have 90 seconds left to complete your work or gracefully cancel your work).